# Android emulator Output

Tags: android

I am running on helloword application as getting started with android application developement. but i cant able to see output in android emulator. it will show only android in the emulator screen. and i am just print "Hello from Brijesh". but it will not display in the emulator of the android. actually i follow the instruction in the following link.
http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html
but not getting out put.
can any one help me out.

thankx.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons you may not be seeing output.  Does the Emulator start?  Does the OS load?  Can you navigate within the Android Emulator (say start the web browser)?  Does program's icon  show up in the launcher?  If you narrow doens what's happening and isn't happening we may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you would like to output some debugging messages to the screen ?
In standard java you can use the System.out.println method, but with android i suggest you use the Dalvik debugger.

Use:

```
Log.i("mytag","My simple message");
```

And se the output by using the Dalvik Debug Monitor

Start the Dalvik Debug Monitor with:

```
c:\android-sdk\tools\ddms.bat
```

Just change the foldername to where you have installed the SDK.

Now the debugger application will start (next to the emulator), and your message will be shown with green text.

Comment: Just a quick update: `ddms` is deprecated; use `tools/monitor` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also view System.out.println commands in the Dalvik Debug Monitor or in LogCat by creating a filter for a Log Tag containing "System.out".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print "Hello from Brijesh" through XMl then use this code.

```
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        />
```

And if you want to print that using java then,

```
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        //Set a text into view
        tv.setText("Hello World");
        //set the view into activity view container
        setContentView(tv);
```