# On studying Android

Tags: android

What is the best way to learn Android? I'm reading Rogers's at al.'s book Android Application Development. However, as I tried the following code, nothing outputs except a mobile phone:

```
package org.qwerty.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

I tried also search for the Dalvik Debug Monitor [Android emulator Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108820/android-emulator-output) but I couldn't find the option where I can open my hello android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[Professional Android Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470344717)" from Wrox by Reto Meier is in my opinion the best book to start learning Android from. Besides the Google documentation

Answer (score 2):

I learned Android with the Google tutorials located [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).

Scroll down on the left side and look for "Tutorials and Sample Code"

Answer (score 0):

You may find this [article](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2007-11-19-n27.html) useful. I just read it and it made sense.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the following articles on [MobiForge](http://mobiforge.com/):

[Getting Started with Android Development](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/getting-started-with-android-development)

[Understanding User Interface in Android - Part 1: Layouts](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts)

[Understanding User Interface in Android - Part 2: Views](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-2-views)

Comment: I would also suggest reading the development guides on http://android.com

Comment: I just read that article Getting Started with Android Development. I can compile my code and run it but I don't see any window like Figure 4 nor anything which displays "Hello Android".

Answer (score 0):

If it's "outputting" a mobile phone then it's probably starting up the emulator. Give it a minute or two as it's actually a virtual machine running a whole OS in there. Your app should show up once it's finished booting.

The emulator should look something like this:

[image: new emulator]
<sub>(source: [android.com](http://developer.android.com/images/emulator-wvga800l.png))</sub>

or this:
[old text http://riddell.us/tutorial/android/android_emulator.png](http://riddell.us/tutorial/android/android_emulator.png)

Comment: I have waited half an hour but still I can't see my application anywhere.

Comment: It was just an emulator window. I had some problems with Built Target but now the code works well.